# Python + PostgreSQL query with filtering by timestamptz column

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to extract data from a PostgreSQL DB while filtering it by a timestamptz column using both date and time.

DB timestamptz column value example : 2020-12-11 17:18:34

I am able to extract data if I only use the dates.

This returns the values in the date range :

```
start_date = '2020-12-11'
end_date = '2020-12-12'
result = pd.read_sql_query(f"""select *
                          from public."userActionsLogs" ual
                          where "timestamp" BETWEEN '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
                          order by "timestamp" ASC""", conn)
```

This returns an empty list :

```
start_date = '2020-12-11 16:10:00'
end_date = '2020-12-11 17:21:00'
result = pd.read_sql_query(f"""select *
                          from public."userActionsLogs" ual
                          where "timestamp" BETWEEN '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
                          order by "timestamp" ASC""", conn)
```

What I've tried and didn't get results:

```
pd.read_sql_query(f"""select *
                      from public."userActionsLogs" ual
                      where to_char("timestamp", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN 
                      '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
                      order by "timestamp" ASC""", conn)
```

Any input is highly apreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the "timestamp" field actually a `timestamptz` type? Does the query work if you run it in `psql`?

Comment: Yes, the "timestamp" field is of type *timestamptz*. I'm using DBeaver as SQL editor and using the same query in the editor that I'm sending from python, returns results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone encountering this issue, the resolution is as follows :

```
import datetime
import pytz
import pandas as pd

start_date = '2020-12-11 16:10:00'
end_date = '2020-12-11 17:21:00'
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens')

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
start = start.replace(tzinfo=tz)

end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end = end.replace(tzinfo=tz)

result = pd.read_sql_query(f"""select *
                          from public."userActionsLogs" ual
                          where "timestamp" BETWEEN '{start}' and '{end}'
                          order by "timestamp" ASC""", conn)
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do:pd.read_sql_query("""select *
                          from public."userActionsLogs" ual
                          where "timestamp" BETWEEN %(start)s and %(end}s
                          order by "timestamp" ASC""", conn, params={"start": start_date}, "end": end_date)

Comment: Realized I forgot an important part. It should be: `BETWEEN %(start)s and %(end}s AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Athens'`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have tested your suggestion.

`start_date = '2020-12-15 14:50:00'
end_date = '2020-12-31 14:50:00'

pd.read_sql_query("""select * from public."userActionsLogs" ual where "timestamp" BETWEEN %(start)s and %(end)s AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Athens' order by "timestamp" ASC""", conn, params={"start": start_date, "end": end_date})
Out[16]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, timestamp, userId, email, eventType]
Index: []`

Thank you four your input anyway.

Comment: Run the query directly in `psql` and see what you get? Also what `SELEC T '2020-12-15 14:50:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE ''Europe/Athens'` gets? What is `TimeZone` set for Postgres server?

Answer (score 0):

This block that you have write is correct. But i've think that you forgot to escape the " ' " symbols.
Try this:

```
pd.read_sql_query(f"""select *
                      from public."userActionsLogs" ual
                      where to_char("timestamp", \'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS\') BETWEEN 
                      \'{start_date}\' and \'{end_date}\'
                      order by "timestamp" ASC""", conn)
```

Comment: Sadly, it still returns an empty DF. I also tried to execute the query with psycopg2 instead of pandas and the result is still an empty list.